# Is it possible to overwrite the versioning number system in Javers?

Tags: java, spring-boot, javers

Currently to denote the version of each modification for an entity, Javers uses a long. I need to use major and minor versions for each modification made to an object. Is it possible to overwrite this implementation of version numbers in Javers or implement major and minor versioning scheme?

Comment: You mean CdoSnapshot.getVersion() ?

Comment: Yes CdoSnapshot.getVersion()

Comment: then no , it's just long